# How can I use the GitHub API (octokit) to filter commits that immediately affect the master branch?

Tags: git, github, github-api, semantic-versioning, octokit

I'm automating semantic versioning using TeamCity and Github, and I'm trying to find a way of counting commits that directly affect the master branch.

Probably best explained by this annotated screenshot from Git-Extensions. I want to automatically calculate the version numbers in the arrows:

[image: git-extensions screenshot]

I'm using ruby and octokit to query the GitHub API as part of my build process. The major and minor version number are incremented manually when a commit or merge qualifies as a major/minor release, so the pseudocode is basically:

1. find the commit corresponding to major.minor.0
2. count every commit since major.minor.0 that changed the state of the master branch
3. set the patch version to commits.count

The problem I'm having is that if I just count the commits to master, each time a pull request is accepted, the commit count increments by *n+1*, where *n* is the number of commits made to the branch. This will work, but it's... inelegant. Yes, I understand that when you accept a pull request, you're effectively accepting the entire history of that branch as part of your 'master' history, but for versioning purposes that doesn't matter.

Does anyone know how I can filter commits via the GitHub API to find out whether the commit directly affected **master** at the point it was created, or is there some reason this is actually impossible?

Thanks!

Comment: That's a great question. Not sure what the best approach would be, and it may be the case that it is impossible to do for some cases. For example, if that commit graph that you have in the question didn't have any branch refs in it except master -- you wouldn't know where to put up version arrows because you wouldn't know which commits were on master. 

And this situation might happen often because after someone merges a branch into master - they'll probably delete it. So all you're left is a big complex graph with a single branch (=master).

Comment: So, in the end, the problem is that a git branch is nothing more than a pointer to a single commit. You don't know which branches pointed to some commit in the past. You can only tell if some commit is reachable from a certain branch (=commit).

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar. You can actually get every pull-request's commit Sha recursively, using the following idea:

```
var filter = new PullRequestRequest() { State = ItemState.Closed }; //for my example, I filtered the pull-requests that are closed
var prs =await client.Repository.PullRequest.GetAllForRepository(Owner,Name,filter);
foreach(var pr in prs){
var prs2 = await client.Repository.PullRequest.Commits (Owner, Name, pr.Number);
}
```

After that, you will get the prs2 Sha attribute and store it to a list.
Then you get all the commits of the repo.

```
var commits = await client.Repository.Commit.GetAll (Owner, Name);
```

Finally, you will compare the list with the sha's from the commits within pull-requests and exclude them from the list which contains all the commits of the repo. That way, there will only be left the commits that are not within a pull-request. Optionally, you can check if those commits are merge commits (commits that merge another's contributor's pull-request) and exclude them too.